# get custom label for custom price magento

Tags: magento, label

I want to get a custom label from a special price or regular price if not have special price.
I can get only the custom label just for special price, but for price i cannot, i dont know from where to start, maybe with else if.
I need help to construct the selection if is only price get price, if special price get special price.

```
<?php 
        // Get the Special Price
        $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice() >= 500;
        // Get price
        $price = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getPrice()>= 500;
        // Get the Special Price FROM date
        $specialPriceFromDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialFromDate();
        // Get the Special Price TO date
        $specialPriceToDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialToDate();
        // Get Current date
        $today =  time();

        if ($specialprice):
            if($today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || $today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)):
    ?>
            <img src="picture/shipping.png" align="right" width="120" height="30" class="onsaleicon" />
    <?php  
            endif;
        endif;
    ?>
```

Add solution:

```
 <?php
    $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getFinalPrice();

    if ($specialprice >= 500):
    ?>

    <img src="picture/shipping.png" align="right" width="120" height="30" class="onsaleicon" />

    <?php
    endif;
    ?
```

Comment: Are you trying to display the shipping image if the price or special prie is greater or equal to 500? if so change this line "if ($specialprice):" to "if ($specialprice || $price ):"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings (`$specialPriceFromDate is a string) with int (time() returns an int ...

Also from_date and to_date for the special price are optional (you can have both, none or just one of them).

What I would suggest:

- Magento provides `$product->getFinalPrice()` function for get the final price
- compare if special_price is present and if it's equal with special_price
- if these 2 are the same (final price and special price) display the special price image

Comment: You are right, 
<code> $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getFinalPrice() >= 500;</code>


if ($specialprice <= 500):
<img src="picture/shipping.png" align="right" width="120" height="30" class="onsaleicon" />
endif;